# Sliding 2D Fast Fourier Transform

Tags: fft, image-processing, audio-processing

How to implement sliding 2D FFT for audio data (shown in the link - R1-chirp)?
I have audio data for an array of 1024 microphone which record audio (for 2 seconds) from a sound source. Microphones are arranged in plane (17 rows and 60 columns). I used 2D FFT to estimate frequency-wavenumber spectrum, however the x-shape signal is not clear. I wonder if using sliding 2D FFT can improve the results.

[image]

http://groups.csail.mit.edu/cag/mic-array/data.html

Comment: So you basically have a 3D signal pressure signal $p(t,x,y)$ with one temporal and two spatial dimensions, so I would have expected a 3D fft. Which spatial dimension did you pick and why? What do you expect to see and why?

Comment: @Hilmar Right, I have 3D pressure signal, however I will only analyze audio signal recorded by one column of microphones. In other words, the pressure signal is simplified to 2D _p(y,t)_. Using 2D Fourier transform, I should get x-shape signal in frequency-wavenumber spectrum. The slope of the straight lines are identical and equal to the velocity of sound in air under room pressure and temperature conditions. To make long story short, the data is 2D (1D spatial and one temporal). I would pick 1D spatial and temporal dimension fo2 2D fft. It is expected to see X-shape signal.

Comment: @RefaatGalal, Do oyu mean something like [Spectrogram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectrogram)?